# Imbalance due to ELO rating

Tags: game-theory, scoring-algorithm

I want to use some rating system in my application. It will look like this:

$TotalRating = rating_1*significanceCoefficient_1 + rating_2*significanceCoefficient_2 + ... + rating_n*significanceCoefficient_n$

Significance coefficient - determines impact of a specific rating.

One of my ratings is [ELO rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). All my other ratings(e.g. novelty of account, activity on the site) have the maximum value(e.g. 100), so, I can easily choose $significanceCoefficient$ for them. But ELO doesn't have a maximum, so I can't choose $significanceCoefficient$ for it.

This creates an imbalance - some users will be overrated due to very high ELO rating and other low ratings, while other users will have medium total rating due to medium ELO rating and high standard ratings.

I came up with a solution - I can set the maximum existing ELO rating of some user as 100% ELO percentage rating, and recalculate ELO percentage rating of other users based on their true ELO rating. E.g.:

```
User1 ELO = 1000 
User2 ELO = 100
User3 ELO = 200
```

Then:

```
User1 ELO percentage rating = 100%
User2 ELO percentage rating = 10%
User3 ELO percentage rating = 20%
```

It's an obvious solution, but not too elegant and requires permanent recount of the ELO percentage rating.

So, I'm looking for better solution for this problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps transform the ELO rating such that infinity maps to 100%? Something like $(1-\exp(-ELO/ref))\cdot 100\%$?

Comment: @IlikeSerena already thought about this, but I think it will be impair users with high rating relatively to users with low rating: growth from 200 to 300 will be more significant, than growth from 800 to 900. Is it fair and right? Still thinking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to set a maximum ELO that you will consider and round all higher ones down to that.  Approaches that rescale $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$ are not very different from this because large differences at the top end will be compressed to almost nothing.

One more general point to consider is that what counts is not the maximum for each component of the rating but the normal range.  If one of your components has a maximum of $100$ but everybody has $99.5$ or higher it does not impact your total as much as one that has a maximum of $10$ but the scores range evenly from $0$ to $10$. Of course, you may want some components to be more important than others, but I would adjust the coefficients based on the range, not the maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have touched an interesting question. I can’t know how the ELO ratings will change and what the maximum value they will reach, because It depends on users. How can I predict a maximum ELO that I will consider? This is a problem because my prediction can be very low or very high. So, I don't want to set this limit with manual guessing.

Comment: I would just take a look at the distribution of the ratings of the users you have and choose a cutoff.  The 95th percentile might be a good choice.  As there is nothing magic about the 95th percentile, you can keep the  cutoff the same even though the ELOs change.  You need to think about how much those last few ELO points should be worth to somebody's rating.

Comment: But I don't have users with an ELO rating yet. So, I can't look at the ELO distribution. Maybe I can find this cutoff value from ELO formula and its parameters? Or somehow do it analytically, not empirically?

Comment: Can you find the ratings of a bunch of people who might represent your users?  The organization that maintains them might have a graph of the distribution available.  Do people brag about having (what they think) is a high one?  I would take a guess and improve the formula as you get data.  You could even leave it out of the rating at the start and add it in later when you get data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps build on what ILikeSerena suggests. Experiment with various functions $f$ that map $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$. The function will have to have $1$ as a horizontal asymptote, which means the increases in a high ELO value won't change $f$ by much, but you can play with where the levelling off becomes most significant.

In fact decreasing the sensitivity of high scores to changes is built in to the ELO rating algorithms. You'd just be exaggerating that.

Check out relatives of the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). You can translate, shift down and stretch so that they start at $f(0) = 0$. You can make the slope there whatever you like. It can be to the left or the right of the inflection point.

But ... if there are really wide variations in the ELO scores there's no obvious "fair" way to scale them. Perhaps assign them low relative weight among all the scores you are averaging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You have solution similar to the solution of the Ross, so, it has similar problem which I described in the comments below his answer. Please check it, maybe you can suggest some solution.

Comment: In this kind of practical problem it's very hard to select an optimal weighting strategy before you've seen any real data. I suggest you try something that seems reasonable, observe how it works and then tinker with it to tune it up.